# Error loading model saved with distributed data parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, pytorch

When loading a model which was saved from a model in distributed mode, the model names are different, resulting in this error. How can I resolve this?

```
  File "/code/src/bert_structure_prediction/model.py", line 36, in __init__                         
    self.load_state_dict(state_dict)                                                                
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1223, in load_state
_dict                                                                                               
    raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(                       
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for BertCoordinatePredictor:                           
        Missing key(s) in state_dict: "bert.embeddings.position_ids", "bert.embeddings.word_embeddin
gs.weight", ...etc.
```

Comment: There are some other pretty good answers to this question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75724281/runtimeerror-errors-in-loading-state-dict/75728573#75728573

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the model names don't match is because DDP wraps the model object, resulting in different layer names when saving the model in distributed data parallel mode (specifically, layer names will have `module.` prepended to the model name). To resolve this, use

```
torch.save(model.module.state_dict(), PATH)
```

instead of

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)
```

when saving from data parallel.

Comment: how would you load the DDP model afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `strict` argument to `False` in the `load_state_dict()` function to ignore non-matching keys:

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path, map_location=torch.device('cpu')), strict=False)
```